# How to pass variables to $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code...

```
$timeout(function(test){
  console.log(test.num);
},0, true, {num:9});
```

However, test is always null so how am I supposed to pass in variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. However, you are running an older version of AngularJS that does not support the 4th parameter. You need at least version 1.4.0.

Usually you don't have to pass parameters explicitly because they are defined in the enclosing scope and are visible in the closure. This works as well:

```
var param = {num:9};
$timeout(function(){
  console.log(param.num);
});
```

If you need to pass a parameter explicitly -- usually because you have to preserve the value of some changing variable --, the answer of @Pankaj-Parkar provides a good workaround. However, I like it better this way:

```
$timeout((function(test) {
    return function() { console.log(test.num) }
})({num: 9}));
```

Comment: OMG you are right, I totally thought I was running 1.4

Comment: I am still losing variables for some reason I think because this is in a for loop and I am trying to get to the index. This is why I need it this way.

Comment: You are right, in this case you have to preserve the value of the counter. You can also use an extra variable inside the body of the loop if you don't like immediately invoked functions.

Comment: @lex82 yes IIFE would great there, thats what i did..because it will restrict the variable scope there. And they would not affect by outer environment

Comment: And I would assume all this is different in ECMA6 rt ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could make it self calling function.

```
(function(test){
  $timeout(function(){
     console.log(test.num);
  },0, true, {num:9});
})({num: 11});
```

anyways your `$timeout` will have that `test` available if its defined outside.